# How to set power_profile at boot

Tags: radeon

So when I log on, I go to a terminal and type

```
echo "mid" | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

which means my laptop works without the fan being constantly ON.

It would be great it I didn't have to do this; I would like this to be done for me, and without me having to enter the password for sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick it in `/etc/rc.local`, before the `exit` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the `rc.local` solution and found it not working for some reason (like other common solutions as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162073/what-prevents-setting-ati-radeon-power-profile-from-boot-and-retaining-it-afte?lq=1)). So I'm posting an **alternative solution using pm-utils**. I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it (I'm new to Linux) but it does what is necessary: **Set the radeon `power_profile` to `low` on boot and retain that setting after suspend-resume**.

Step 1: Create hook

```
gksu gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/radeon-power_profile
```

Step 2: Fill in the desired setting

```
#!/bin/sh

echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile

exit 0
```

Step 3: Make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/radeon-power_profile
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had try it but doesn't work for me
`echo "low" | sudo password /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile`
or
`echo "low" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile`
when I log in and enter 
`cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile`
still gives me `"high"`

running - 12.04 x64 , 3.2.0-25-generic

Comment: This is not an answer - use comments for things like this, not answers. First check your card allows that setting. Log in, start terminal, use the command in my question. Then use your `cat` command to see whether your setting is set. Then put the line in `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit 0`. Here you want `echo "low" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile` as this script is run by root, so you don't want/need `sudo` (and anyway this won't work). Then reboot, login and test.

Comment: sorry for my post. But this stil Doesn't Work! as I say it before. My  GPU is goint really hot after I hit Enter in the boot menu. is there a solution to add this command from start not after login ?

Comment: Do you mean rc.local is not being executed before you log in? Or not being executed at all? Or that the echo "low"... thing isn't working from the command line? rc.local: Check execution bits (`ls -l /etc/rc.local` are set). Check it is being executed - e.g. put in a line like `logger -t rc.local boo`, then reboot, wait 5 mins, login and `less /var/log/syslog` and search for "rc.local"  - the timestamp will show you when it was run. The comments say it runs at end of multiuser boot levels, which means that it should be running by the time you see your login screen.

Comment: Jun 22 21:15:51 Zion AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Get updates()
Jun 22 21:15:53 Zion AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/4baf315f513b4dd39a6b39226808e8a7
Jun 22 21:17:01 Zion CRON[2988]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 22 21:19:54 Zion rc.local: boo
Jun 22 21:20:39 Zion kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Jun 22 21:20:39 Zion rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="970" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15

Comment: I also create a dir with rc.local - mkdir /home/tosho/alabala
echo "low" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
exit 0
the directory is created after I login but still when I write `cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile` it shows **high** instead of **low** which for me means that the command is not executed. I did another tutorial [link](http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-open-source-ati-radeon-driver-power-usage-tweaks/) where I made a script that runs on startup but still my power_profile remains in "high"

Comment: also after resume from standby `power_profile` is set again to `high`

Answer (score 0):

alt-f2:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/init.d/ati-power-save
```

write this in ati-power-save file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ATI power save
echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

save and run these commands:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/ati-power-save 
sudo update-rc.d ati-power-save defaults 99
```

[as described in here](http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-open-source-ati-radeon-driver-power-usage-tweaks/)