# Will overheating of Dell Inspiron N5010 stop if I remove the graphics card

Tags: 12.04, ati, graphics, dell, overheating

I notice that my laptop (Dell Inspiron N5010) is frequently overheating even with the necessary fglrx drivers installed. If I manually remove the graphics card(or get it removed by someone more experienced), will it stop overheating? Everything else is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the latest microcode for your cpu? This usually solves a few issues including cpu overheating. You can find detailed instructions on installing the microcode for your CPU by visiting [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/microcode). Microcode for both Intel CPUs and AMDs is installed through Synaptic Package Manager so no need to worry about adding some new ppa or similar.

As for your video card, try to install a genuine driver from [AMD support page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download#) for your video card. It will take a lot of heat from your CPU once the driver is properly installed and working :).

You can visit [this page](http://itsfoss.com/solve-overheating-issue-battery-life-ubuntu-1304/) to learn more about overheating and how to deal with this problem by installing one or more of those programs suggested in that article. Read the comments at the end of the article, there are some interesting solutions in there too.

Comment: I have an ATI Raedon HD 5740 Graphics card.

Comment: I should have known better. You mentioned that in your question. I updated my answer, and added a link to some useful article about overheating and how to deal with that. Read the comments too, there are some useful links inside those comments.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue because of hybrid graphics. [This guide](http://rudrageek.com/linux-now-supports-hybrid-graphics-systems-ubuntu-13-10/) worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: No I don't have hybrid graphics. Its the only card.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Solution using pm-utils that can be found at  [How to set power_profile at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115142/how-to-set-power-profile-at-boot)

This sets the radeon power_profile to low on boot and retains that setting after suspend-resume.

Open terminal.

Step 1: create hook

sudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/radeon-power_profile

Step 2: fill in the desired setting (low, medium, high)

#!/bin/sh

echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method

echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile

exit 0

Step 3: make it executable

sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/radeon-power_profile

Step 4: Use "exit" in terminal to finish.

Step 5: Reboot