# Laptop running very hot

Tags: overheating, temperature

I've just read a thread where a laptop running at 60C was too hot. Mine often runs at 80C.

[image: Picture of <code>sensors</code>; everything is 80C]

I notice that this happens often when I have Chromium open. There's nothing using up tons of CPU in `htop`, though:

[image: htop]

I've got an HP Envy DV6T 7300. I know HPs are notorious for shitty temperature control, but should it be running this hot? I don't notice this kind of temperature on Windows (which I only log into to play games).

Comment: Yeah, this is too much, mine goes 60 degrees max.

Comment: Software issues notwithstanding, you may want to check your laptop's fan. Make sure it's running (you should feel air blowing on your hand about an inch away when the laptop is running hard). Blow some canned air through it to get any dust out. I have to do that every eight months or so, or my laptop starts overheating too easily. If you DON'T feel air coming out, open up the laptop and thoroughly dust out the fan. If it still doesn't work, you may need a *new* fan.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For me it was due to an outdated kernel. Specifically, it was with a haswell cpu and ubuntu 14.04. The laptop idled at 60 degrees Celsius.

What is your kernel version and what os are you running?

Use the command `uname -a` in the terminal to determine the kernel version.

Edit: This could also be a graphics card issue, check your graphics card drivers if you have one to see if they are up to date. Search for `additional drivers` in the search box and verify that you are using modern drivers.

Edit: I haven't tried any of these methods but they might be worth a look.

http://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/

Comment: The kernel version I'm using is ``Linux Alcatraz 3.19.0-58-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:05:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
``

Comment: Are you using haswell, broadwell, skylake or one of AMD's cpu's?

Comment: It's an Intel i7 (this, exactly: ``Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz``). There's no dedicated graphics card; it's an Intel HD4000

Comment: Well, kernel 3.19 should support your cpu. Do you have a dedicated GPU by chance?

Comment: Nope, Intel HD4000. :(

Comment: Have you checked for dust or if the thermal paste is completely dry?

Comment: I've checked for dust, but not the thermal paste. That's something I'll do tomorrow

Comment: Check the URL linked in my answer first. Once you remove thermal paste, you have to reapply it. Looks like Intel created tools to help control cpu temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Intel i7 with Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV770 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4850/4870].  Ubuntu 14.04.03.

This worked for me.

Solution using pm-utils that can be found at  [How to set power_profile at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115142/how-to-set-power-profile-at-boot)

This sets the radeon power_profile to low on boot and retains that setting after suspend-resume

Open terminal

Step 1: create hook

sudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/radeon-power_profile

Step 2: fill in the desired setting (low, medium, high)

#!/bin/sh

echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method

echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile

exit 0

Step 3: make it executable

sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/radeon-power_profile

Step 4: Use "exit" in terminal to finish.

Step 5: Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem for months running 22.04 LTS where it consistently ran HOT, up to 80 C. Other distros always ran cooler but I kept coming back to Ubuntu. I recently stripped out snap, entirely, and now my laptop is running at about 40-50 C. I can't prove or explain why snap makes things hotter but it worked for me.
I followed the tutorial at debugpoint dot com slash remove-snap-ubuntu
FWIW:
Laptop Make: Model > Framework: Laptop AB 
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
DE: GNOME 42.5 
Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
WM: Mutter 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.700GHz [118.4°F]
CPU Usage: 10% 
Disk (/): 14G / 228G (7%)
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
GPU Driver: i915 
Memory: 5186MiB / 15786MiB (32%)
Resolution: 2256x1504