# How do I enable Integrated Graphics on my laptop?

Tags: intel-graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I recently acquired a Acer Aspire 7741G for cheap. It has Intel i5-460M and a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650. I installed Ubuntu 16.04

It runs at 60 C and eventually will shut down from overheating even when I'm not using it so I want to disable the graphics card and use intel. All the Google suggestions I tried don't work.

1. Do I even have integrated graphics? i5-460M is supposed to right? But when I do `lsci | grep VGA`, nothing.
2. `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo` is no such file or directory
3. Any way that I can set the power profile to low?

Comment: in your question, you made a typo `lsci` - it should be `lspci`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue mate. The only fix is this (Since AMD hasnt released OC GPU drivers yet on 16.04 and in 16.10): [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04/16.10 and AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-14-04-5-and-amd-graphics)

I still havent fixed it yet, trying to downgrade my XORG. You may want to try the other options before downgrading to 14.04.5 (It still has LTS till 2019)

I consider 14.04.5 as a last shot. I am not sure how are we (You and I) suppose to make Oibaf's drivers work or even install them. Since you have an AMD GPU (Not sure if it is supported in AMDGPU-Pro method in the main link) you may want to try that. So head over to: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx and see if your GPU is supported for AMDGPU-Pro.

I believe you can set the power profile low in AMD via `amdconfig --intial` and configure more stuff from there. I havent tried it yet cause I am still trying to get my GPU to work so I can game myself.

Good luck and I will keep you updated as I try; and I hope you will do the same as we both try to help each other out.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using pm-utils that can be found at  [How to set power_profile at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115142/how-to-set-power-profile-at-boot)

This sets the radeon power_profile to low on boot and retains that setting after suspend-resume

Open terminal

Step 1: create hook

sudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/radeon-power_profile

Step 2: fill in the desired setting (low, medium, high)

#!/bin/sh

echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method

echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile

exit 0

Step 3: make it executable

sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/radeon-power_profile

Step 4: Use "exit" in terminal to finish.

Step 5: Reboot